# Настройка отладки Lua-скриптов в SciTE v. 1.75 ( Windows 10)

Tags: lua

Я использую для создания Lua-скриптов **SciTE v.1.75** в **Windows 10**.
Меня все устраивает, но как мне выполнять отладку скрипта в данном редакторе?
Там что-то нужно устанавливать дополнительно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или может есть что-то аналогичное с встроенным функционалом отладки?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/DebuggingLuaCode

Comment: Пробовал один из этих вариантов. У меня вылетает при запуске. @ESkri